How do I set container to viewport height in safari browser?
I'm building a static page for my blog using GitHub pages, and I'm having troubling correctly fitting my container-banner to the height of my iPhone's viewport on the safari browser.
Referencing this webpage, you'll notice that the banner content perfectly fits the page (since my navbar and container-banner sum to 100dvh), and you can scroll to view the blog content further below. My CSS is as follows:
.container-banner {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  height: 94dvh;
  padding: 0px 40px;
}

nav,
footer {
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  font-family: "Amatic SC";
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0px 40px;
  height: 6dvh;
}


However, if you open the above page in a safari browser, the content will adjust as you scroll downwards. I believe this is because safari's navbar disappears, and the flex content is dynamically resizing since the container-banner is resizing as well per dvh's name.
I don't like this UI. I'd prefer that when the page loads, it perfectly fits to the viewport (as it does now), and that it doesn't resize the content as you scroll downwards. What part of my CSS should I correct? Thank you.

It’s because you are using “dvh” instead of “vh”.
Unlike “vh,” “dvh” represents a percentage of the document height, rather than the viewport height.
From https://www.w3.org/TR/2021/WD-css-values-4-20211016/#dynamic-viewport-percentage-units

The dynamic viewport-percentage units (dv*) are defined with respect to the dynamic viewport size: the viewport sized with dynamic consideration of any UA interfaces that are dynamically expanded and retracted. This allows authors to size content such that it can exactly fit within the viewport whether or not such interfaces are present.

